# Prevent PowerPoint from forcefully inserting new lines after putting a hyphen "-"

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, newlines

In a bullet-list, my first point contains the text

> Dot-notation: $.store.book[0].title

The container text-box looks like so (as you can see, the second point is also affected):
[image: Automatic-linebreak-after-hyphen]

The **problem** is that the **hyphen** between `Dot` and `notation` causes **automatically a new line** to be inserted right after that hyphen, which is totally undesired.
I can't seem to get rid of this automatic formatting; yet, I'd prefer to have 100% control over *when* a new line is being inserted.

---

**EDIT** on comment "*go to symbols and copy-paste it*":

As for me, going to special symbols in the top menu manually and find these symbols cluttered and differently available for each encoding/font, is very unpractical. It should work right of the bat with a keyboard shortcut or hotkey. Yet, it does not in my PowerPoint installation and I could not figure out how to customize these hotkeys somewhere within PowerPoint.

---

**EDIT** on checking "*AutoFormat as you type*":

Following [these instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/393935/how-to-prevent-powerpoint-from-resizing-text/), I've checked out said menu, but did not find anything associated with the issue of automatically inserting new lines after hyphens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a **workaround** and probably also the cause of the problem:

### 1) Short answer

Replace all `spaces` with spaces made with keyboard (i.e. using the "space"-key). The spaces might not be actual spaces, because the text could be copy-pasted from somewhere else.

### 2) Detailed answer

I'd copied the text in question from some `HTML`-displayed text in VS Code. This apparently meant that the `space` characters were not "normal", even though one cannot detect it with the bare eye; it's hidden.
Thus, all of the text after the `hyphens` was treated like one entire `string`; not like several strings separated by ("normal") spaces.

In order to get rid of the problem, I had to replace all of these "false" spaces by "real" ones, which I simply produced via the keyboard `space`-key. After that, no forceful line break happened anymore.